# Why Thread 2 not available?

Tags: c#, threadpool

In below little console application, I'm printing main thread Id and the 5 other thread, it's printing 1, 3,4,5,6,7, but not 2. Is thread 2 not available and how this number is generated?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToList().ForEach(f =>
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }).Start();

        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

> Thread 1
>   Thread 3
>   Thread 4
>   Thread 5
>   Thread 6
>   Thread 7

Comment: Try to run it again. You will probably have other results :)

Comment: every time same result. I know it should different, how this numbering happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread with Id=2 is garbage collector thread. You can check its Id by running finalizer:

```
class Test
{
    ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var test = new Test();
    test = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Although correct, be careful not to assume that the garbage collector thread will always be 2. As far as I can see there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I agree, we cannot guarantee until this is documented.